# ISO8601 Format are different in MongoDB and iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, node.js, mongodb, date-formatting

I want to post a `Date` with `IOS8601` format from iOS to NodeJS(mongoDB), and get from NodeJS to iOS.

But the dateformat are different from both platform.

iOS side: **2019-05-26T17:10:10Z**
mongoDB side: **2019-05-26T17:10:10.000Z**

which means the date example post to mongoDB, then the date get back with the extra `.000`.

**For iOS**:

```
extension Date {
  var ISO8601String: String? {
      let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
      return formatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

The ISO8601String output is: **YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ**

**For mongoDB**

Schema:

```
var FooSchema = Schema({

    date: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
let date = new Date(req.body.date) // I also used req.body.date directlly
new Foo(date: date)
```

On iOS side get the ISO8601 `date` was added `.000`. 
which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Here is the [doc reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/):
[image]

Do I have to convert at least from one side?

Comment: Pretty sure the milliseconds are part of the standard, does iOS not ignore it when you try to parse the string? For mongo side I'd definitely store it as a Date data type, since then you can perform date comparison on it, it's also smaller in size since it's stored as an int. You can then still extract either the timestamp or the ISO string from it

Comment: @bsod yes, Node.JS side mongoose just store `Date` type. These properties just being read-from and written-to. I was thought timestamps and ISO8601 date are all just strings. Should be the same format and no difference. I think I might need to change it to milliseconds.

Comment: @Plancke What do you mean "not ignore it"? If I understood correctly, you are saying use `Date` type, but just iOS side just use Node.JS date formate to parse? If yes, it's possible. But on iOS side there is an `ISO8601DateFormatter` type. If I use it directly, then no need to set format string like `YYYY-MM-dd...`.

Comment: @Plancke You said you story a `Date` type because comparison, the milliseconds can't perform a comparison?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I need : ) Have thought on Node.JS side `Date().toISOString`, no need at all now.

Comment: @WilliamHu if you store it as a timestamp that's fine too, just don't store an ISO string in there, because then you do lose that functionality. I usually prefer the date data type though, since then visualizers are able to properly display the ISO string directly, and not just a random number. Though i've definitely also used epoch before as well

Comment: @Plancke thanks, agreed, I prefer to the ISO `Date` type too. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS you can generate a formatter that includes milliseconds in iOS 11 and later with:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
```

If you need to do this with iOS versions before that, you have to use `DateFormatter`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```